# Created Point still throws NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, point

In a little Project of mine I try to set a `Point` to another `Point` in `OnTouchEvent()`. Both points are created in the **Constructor** like this:

```
package com.example.samuel.truespeedgame;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;


public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
        private SurfaceHolder holder;
        private SurfaceViewThread surfaceViewThread;

        public Point clickPoint, playerPoint, startPoint;


        GamePanel(Context context) {
            super(context);

            maxSpeed = 20;

            playerPoint = new Point(200,200); //very normal instanciating of Points i guess
            startPoint = new Point(200,200);
            clickPoint = new Point(200,200);
}
```

My `OnTouchEvent()` looks like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent motionEvent) {

    switch (motionEvent.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {

        // Player has touched the screen
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(clickPoint != null)
                clickPoint.set((int)motionEvent.getX(),(int)motionEvent.getY());
            else if(clickPoint == null) clickPoint = new Point((int)motionEvent.getX(),(int)motionEvent.getY());

            startPoint = playerPoint; //Here gets the error thrown

            break;

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:

    }
    return true;
}
```

It was a **NullPointerException** before I rebuild the Project. Now the `playerPoint.x` and `.y` is always **0**.

Comment: Any other places you set `playerPoint` ?

Comment: This line `else if(clickPoint == null)` is not good. According to your logic, should be enough to change to `else` .

Comment: Seems like your motionEvent.x is always 0? Have you checkt x and y values of motionEvent? Maybe you can use motionEvent.getX with the pointer Id? See here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MotionEvent.html#getX(int)

Comment: playerPoint is only set at constructor so always 0, isn't this expected?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't instantiate GamePanel your playerPoint will be null.